# commonJS require a default exported function returns default function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I came across something something in JavaScript that I found baffling and I'm hoping to find an explanation for.

I'm writing a Jest test to that requires mocking a custom module that I've written, which the helper function I'm testing depends on. In addition, I need to override a method from the custom module to change its normal output to throw an exception instead to test the unhappy path.

Here's how my mock module looks like:

```
// ../helperFunctions/__mocks__/CreateRequestObject.js

// This is the mock function for getFileList()
export default function () {
 return {
    post: () => ({
      data: [
       "folder1/file1.doc",
       "folder1/folder2/file2.doc",
       "folder1/folder3/file3.doc"
      ],
    }),
  };
}
```

```
// ../helperFunctions/CreateRequestObject.js

/* This function returns an axios request object with pre-configured base url */

import axios from 'axios';

export default function (config = {
  baseURL: 'https://www.example.com',
  timeout: 10000,
  responseType: 'json',
}) {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: config.baseURL,
    timeout: config.timeout,
    responseType: config.responseType,
  });
}
```

```
// ../helperFunctions/RequestActions.js
import createRequestObject from './CreateRequestObject';
import RequestException from '../exceptions/RequestExceptions';

async function getFileList(path) {
  /*
    Returns:
    * [] if there are no files or folders found in the path
    * An array of file names as strings if one or more files are found

    Throws:
    * RequestException when request fails
  */

  try {
    const api = createRequestObject();
    const response = await api.post('/endpoint', { path });
    const dataSet = response.data;
    return dataSet;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new RequestException(e);
  }
}

export default getFileList;
```

```
// ../helperFunctions/helperFunctions.test.js
import createRequestObject from '../helperFunctions/CreateRequestObject';
import getFileList from '../helperFunctions/RequestActions';
import RequestException from '../exceptions/RequestExceptions';

test(`getFileList() API call failure should throw RequestException error`,
  async () => {
    // Arrange
    const path = 'folder1/folder2/folder3';

    const createRequestObject = require('../helperFunctions/CreateRequestObject');
    createRequestObject.default.post.mockImplementation() => ({
        post: () => {
          throw new RequestExeception({
            message: 'No Network',
            config: {
              baseURL: 'https://www.example.com',
              url: '/endpoint',
          })
        }
      }));

    // Act
    const data = await getFileList(path);

    // Assert
    expect(data).toThrow();

  });
```

From [Jests' documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules), it suggests to first call `jest.mock('path/to/module/tobe/mocked');` then, require the original file `const myModule = require('path/to/module/tobe/mocked');`. After that, call `myModule.methodName.mockImplementation(() => {...});` in my test to change the implementation.

However, when I try to call the method after `require`, I get an error stating that the method does not exist. Doing a `console.log()` shows `[default: Function_]`.

Out of curiosity, I called `console.log(myModule.default())` and I see `{ post: [Function post] }`.

Going to the mock module file using VSCode and hovering my mouse over the keyword `default`, I see the following overlay:

```
function default(): {
   post: () => ({ data: string[] });
}
```

My question is why is default returned as a function when I require from a file that uses `export default` keywords? How does export default function?

In addition, calling mockImplementation isn't working and I don't understand why.

Comment: Please post the exact contents of your mocked `myModule.js`. Does it really have any exports? And how is the actual module implemented? How is it loaded?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I've added some additional details. Hopefully that will make it a bit more clear. I'm trying to grapple with replacing the implementation of the post method you see there and I haven't been successful. I followed the examples from Jests' documentation, but have yet to succeed.

Comment: `createRequestObject.default` is a function that will *return* an object with a `post` method. It doesn't have a `.post` property itself. So yes, `createRequestObject.default.post.mockImplementation` does not exist and should throw an exception. (Also, the rest of that line seems to cause a syntax error, missing a parenthesis maybe?)

Comment: So if I want to override that post method when getFileList() gets called in helperFunctions.test.js, how can I do this with Jest? I tried to call `createRequestObject.default().post.mockImplementationOnce(() => {...}) but it is still telling me that mockImplementationOnce() is not a function

Comment: All you need to do is write the `helperFunctions/__mocks__/CreateRequestObject.js` file (with the same API as the original), and then call `jest.mock('../helperFunctions/CreateRequestObject')`.

Comment: Yes, I've done that for the happy path, but now I want to modify it one time to test for the case where `getFileList()` throws an exception. In the regular mock implementation, I am returning a list of paths to files.

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

I'm not sure if this is the way to solve this problem. I welcome others who are more knowledgable to chime in setting up tests using Jest Framework.

Originally, this is how I thought I was supposed to structure the test:

1. Create a mock version of my custom made module 'createRequestObject' in `/helperFunctions/__mocks__/CreateRequestObject.js`
2. In HelperFunctions.test.js, call `jest.mock('../helperFunctions/CreateRequestObject')`
3. add `import createRequestObject from '../helperFunctions/CreateRequestObject'` at the top, then in my specific test, call `createRequestObject.mockImplementation(() => { throw new RequestException(...)}`

When I did this, I ran into the error message "createRequestObject" is not a function.

This is because when the function was imported, the function had executed and returned an object.

The next issue was that the object is a fixed object containing a post method that returns an object with some data inside. None of this can be modified. Think of it as a static immutable image.

What I want is the ability to change the implementation of my module on the fly between tests to ensure my helper function `getFileList()`, which will call `createRequestObject()` behind the scenes to a) return the set of data mimicking a successful API call or b) thrown an error when the API call fails.

## Solution

Inside `/helperFunctions/__mocks__/CreateRequestObject.js`, I now have the following code:

`export default jest.fn();`

`jest.fn()` will return an object with access to all of the mocking methods that I need to change implementation on the fly!

In my `HelperFunctions.test.js`, I can now import createRequestObject as I did above, but now call `createRequestObject.mockImplementationOnce(() => {...})` multiple times to setup for my tests, which is my intention in the first place!

I hope this information helps others who are also facing similar issues.